# Mac mail.app crashes almost immediately after startup

Tags: macos, email

July 11, 2014

OS X 10.9.4

The mail.app has been crashing consistently almost as soon as I open the app. I have a "godaddy" mail (IMAP config) account and a gmail account connected. I've removed the mail.app and reinstalled OS X in order to hopefully "fix" the mail.app but it's had no effect.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

I've attached the error report below:

```
Process:         Mail [4815]
Path:            /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Identifier:      com.apple.mail
Version:         7.3 (1878.6)
Build Info:      Mail-1878006000000000~1
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [240]
Responsible:     Mail [4815]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-07-11 12:24:46.606 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  REMOVED


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[MCArchiveFileWrapper regularFileContents] *** this method is only for regular file type NSFileWrappers'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cb2425c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff88333e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cb2410c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8bb5d5aa -[NSFileWrapper regularFileContents] + 94
4   MailUI                              0x00007fff88d2232a -[MUIWebAttachmentController _generateAttachmentMarkup] + 782
5   MailUI                              0x00007fff88d21977 -[MUIWebAttachmentController initWithWebAttachment:controller:] + 239
6   MailUI                              0x00007fff88d2ce8a -[MUIWKViewController _reloadDocument] + 513
7   MailUI                              0x00007fff88d2cc26 -[MUIWKViewController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 284
8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8baf2f28 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 387
9   Foundation                          0x00007fff8bb139c7 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) _addObserver:forProperty:options:context:] + 306
10  Foundation                          0x00007fff8bb136f7 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] + 112
11  MailUI                              0x00007fff88d2ca8f -[MUIWKViewController setRepresentedObject:] + 287
12  Mail                                0x000000010d0b07fd Mail + 411645
13  Mail                                0x000000010d0b067f Mail + 411263
14  Mail                                0x000000010d0b0324 Mail + 410404
15  Foundation                          0x00007fff8baf2f28 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 387
16  Foundation                          0x00007fff8baf20f8 NSKeyValueDidChange + 453
17  Foundation                          0x00007fff8bb64641 NSKeyValueDidChangeForObservance + 126
18  Foundation                          0x00007fff8bb642db -[NSKeyValueObservance observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 248
19  Foundation                          0x00007fff8baf2f28 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 387
20  Foundation                          0x00007fff8baf20f8 NSKeyValueDidChange + 453
21  Foundation                          0x00007fff8baf6be6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 118
22  Mail                                0x000000010d0badf7 Mail + 454135
23  Foundation                          0x00007fff8bb120b5 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 75
24  Foundation                          0x00007fff8baf18a1 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 631
25  Foundation                          0x00007fff8baf154b __NSOQSchedule_f + 64
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c82a28d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c831ef0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ca8b4f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
29  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ca46714 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ca45e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
31  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d1d2a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
32  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d1d27b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
33  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d1d25bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
34  AppKit                              0x00007fff8af4d24e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
35  AppKit                              0x00007fff8af4c89b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
36  AppKit                              0x00007fff8af4099c -[NSApplication run] + 553
37  AppKit                              0x00007fff8af2b783 NSApplicationMain + 940
38  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff851395fd start + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ee45866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff857ce35c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff87357b1a abort + 125
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8c75bf31 abort_message + 257
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8c781952 default_terminate_handler() + 264
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8833430d _objc_terminate() + 103
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8c77f1d1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8c77f246 std::terminate() + 54
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff883340b0 objc_terminate + 9
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c82a2a1 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c831ef0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca8b4f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca46714 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca45e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d1d2a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d1d27b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d1d25bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af4d24e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af4c89b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af4099c -[NSApplication run] + 553
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af2b783 NSApplicationMain + 940
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff851395fd start + 1
```

Threads 1-25 REMOVED

```
Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff73718310  rcx: 0x00007fff52bb1ea8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000707  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff52bb1ed0  rsp: 0x00007fff52bb1ea8
   r8: 0x6e6f697470656378   r9: 0x00007fff8737f8d0  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff52bb2030  r13: 0x0000608000134c80  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x00007fff52bb1f10
  rip: 0x00007fff8ee45866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x0000000114d2d000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

BINARY IMAGES REMOVED FROM REPORT

```
External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 3816
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=238.1M resident=133.1M(56%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=105.1M(44%)
Writable regions: Total=1.2G written=26.6M(2%) resident=68.6M(6%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.1G(94%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
CG backing stores                     676K
CG image                             6492K
CG raster data                       12.5M
CG shared images                      212K
CoreAnimation                        20.7M
CoreData                                4K
CoreData Object IDs                  4100K
CoreImage                            2088K
CoreServices                         1616K
CoreUI image data                      16K
Foundation                              4K
Image IO                              796K
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                       8K
MALLOC                              110.1M
MALLOC (admin)                         32K
Memory Tag 241                        116K
Memory Tag 242                         12K
Memory Tag 251                         96K
OpenCL                                208K
SQLite page cache                    1920K
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                19.8M
VM_ALLOCATE                          16.7M
WebKit Malloc                        1232K
__DATA                               33.6M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                           67.0M
__TEXT                              171.1M
__UNICODE                             544K
mapped file                          72.5M
shared memory                           4K
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                 1.6G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      600.2M


Model: MacBookPro11,2, BootROM MBP112.0138.B02, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.18f6
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (6.30.223.154.65)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.6f1 14216, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Thunderbolt Ethernet, Ethernet, en4
PCI Card: Apple 57762-A0, Ethernet Controller, Thunderbolt@195,0,0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: My Passport 0740
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
Thunderbolt Device: Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter, Apple Inc., 1, 5.5
```

Answer (score -2):

Install the OS X 10.9.4 Combo Update

Comment: Adding more details (preferably step by step instructions) to this answer would be appreciated.